# Each time a new platform spawns, rotate it 90 degrees from the previous

Tags: unity, c#, rotation, transformation

All I want is when the platform changes its position on the x or the z axis, then rotate the whole platform by 90 degrees.

When I try to do this with the following code, I don't see any change - the new platform always has the same rotation, no matter which of the two rotation methods below I use.

```
public GameObject platform;
public Transform lastPlatform;
Vector3 lastPosition;
Vector3 newPos;
bool stop;

private Quaternion rotationQuaternion;

void Start()
{
    lastPosition = lastPlatform.position;
    StartCoroutine(SpawnPlatforms());

    rotationQuaternion = transform.rotation;
}

IEnumerator SpawnPlatforms()
{
    while (!stop)
    {
        GeneratePosition();

        Instantiate(platform, newPos, rotationQuaternion * Quaternion.identity);

        lastPosition = newPos;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
    }
}

void GeneratePosition()
{
    newPos = lastPosition;

    int rand = Random.Range(0, 2);

    if (rand > 0)
    {
        newPos.x += 1.5f;
        // One way I tried - no visible effect.
        transform.rotation = rotationQuaternion * Quaternion.Euler(0, 90, 0); 
    }
    else
    {
        newPos.z += 1.5f;
        // Another way I tried - also no visible effect.
        platform.transform.Rotate(0, 90, 0);
    }
}
```

I appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Myself, I'd be inclined to bundle up information and behaviour for your "spawning cursor" into its own type, something like this:

```
[System.Serializable]
public struct SpawnPoint {
    public Vector3 position;
    public Quaternion orientation;

    public void Step(float distance) {
        if (Random.value < 0.5) {
            position.x += distance;
        } else {
            position.z += distance;
        }

        orientation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 90, 0) * orientation;
    }
}
```

Then you can set aside a single member variable to hold that cursor's state:

```
SpawnPoint _spawn;
```

Initialize it at startup:

```
void Start() {
    _spawn.position = lastPlatform.position;
    _spawn.orientation = transform.rotation;
}
```

Then, when you want to spawn a platform, step your cursor, and spawn at the cursor:

```
IEnumerator SpawnPlatforms()
{
    while (!stop)
    {
        _spawn.Step(1.5f);

        var newPlatform = Instantiate(platform, _spawn.position, _spawn.orientation);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
    }
}
```

The reason your approach wasn't working before was because you were always passing the same rotation to `Instantiate` method:

```
Instantiate(platform, newPos, rotationQuaternion * Quaternion.identity);
```

`rotationQuaternion` is only ever assigned once, in the `Start()` method, so for every subsequent execution of this line, it will always have the same value - no matter how you've changed `transform.rotation` or `platform.rotation` in the meantime.

This would be very easy to see if you used a `Debug.Log(rotationQuaternion)` or set a breakpoint to examine the value of the variable during execution, so be sure not to skip those steps when debugging your code!

Comment: Ooooh, thank you so much for the really-really detailed answer. You gave me a better understanding! All I had to edit is to not * orientation, so the texture only rotates when the position changes to the X or to the Z. Thank you a lot again!